# How I can know if in flutter in app purchase user manually cancel the subscription?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

i am using flutter in_app_purchase package, i have implemented the logic for subscription i am stuck at if user manually cancels the subscription, the app does not know that subscription is cancelled ?

```
var data = await InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails(ids);
var productDetails = data.productDetails;
print(productDetails.length); //if user cancelled the subscription there is still data present

StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>> _subscription = InAppPurchase.instance.purchaseStream.listen((data){
   print(data.length);// Similarly here also if user cancelled the subscription
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using firebase, and you've set up hooks for cloud functions, when the user cancels, the subscription will toggle to inactive.  [You can follow this codelab for the full implementation.](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#0)

Then you'll need use firebase to control application content based on subscription active/inactive.

If you don't want to use firebase, you'll need to use PurchaseDetails and specifically the PurchaseStatus found on the PurchaseDetails.

This is just one summarized way to do it:

```
final InAppPurchase _inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;
```

then in initState:

```
final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchases = _inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;
```

Listen to that stream:

```
_streamSubscription = purchases.listen((purchasesDetailsList) {
_listenToPurchases(purchaseDetailsList); });
```

Then your `_listenToPurchases` method will take a `List<Purchasetails>` and you'll process that as you need to.  If you get a PurchaseDetails.PurchaseStatus that is cancelled, you'll remove permissions on your app.

Comment: isn't there any other way without firebase ??

Comment: Put an explanation for cases that don't want to use firebase.  Hope that helps!